# Can "since" and "as" be used interchangeably in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions, conjunctions

> They sat at the counter as/since all the seats were filled.

I've seen both versions. For example [here](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=uAU4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA600&lpg=PA600&dq=%22all%20the%20seats%20were%20filled%22&source=bl&ots=3GS053hSKY&sig=ACfU3U36E4PKBJfx30tWh_ICsVFFzG_ZNw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQh62J8qThAhXWyYsBHf9SASkQ6AEwC3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22all%20the%20seats%20were%20filled%22&f=false).

Are *as* and *since* are interchangeable in situations like these? If so, in which situations are they not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are interchangeable here. They are generally interchangeable when they have the sense of *because*. They are not interchangeable when they have other senses, especially their senses that relate to time. When used in relation to time, *as* means ***at the same time***, and *since* means ***all the time after***.

Answer (score 0):

They are not interchangeable here; "since" creates an ambiguity as it is generally associated with time. Consider: "They sat at the counter since all the seats were filled." There is ambiguity in this usage - does "since" relate to time or cause? Using "as" instead eliminates the ambiguity. Consider: "They sat at the counter as all the seats were filled." That seems to nail causation rather than time.